# if $A=\{x : x^2 - 17 = 0 , x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ then find the value of $n(\wp(\wp(\wp(A))))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help me in Solving this question.

if $A=\{x : x^2 - 17 = 0  , x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

then find the value of $n(\wp(\wp(\wp(A))))$.

What I Tried is below:

$x^2 -17 =0$

$x= \pm \sqrt{17}$

So the number of elements of set A is 2  : $+\sqrt{17}$ or $-\sqrt{17}$

So  $n(\wp(\wp(\wp(A))))$ =  $(((2^2)^2)^2)$

Where $n(\wp(A))$ = $2^2$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Start by finding $n(A)$, for example

Comment: Is $\wp$ the power set operator?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes P is the power set operator...

Comment: @5xum: I added what I did..

Comment: Also, note that $n\bigl(\wp(A)\bigr)=2^{n(A)},$ which is not (in general) equal to $n(A)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is wrong, because $\sqrt{17}$ is not an element of $A$. Remember, a value $x$ is an element of $A$ if:

- $x^2-17=0$
- $x\in\mathbb Q$.

$x=\sqrt{17}$ does not satisfy one of these two conditions.

Comment: Please can you provide the correct answer to this with reason...

Comment: @Shubhra No, I suggest **you** take my comments into account and try to solve the problem.

Comment: Since +√17 or −√17 are not rational numbers so the set essentially becomes null set .    So the result would be n(℘(℘(℘(A)))) = (((2^0)^2)^2)

Where n(℘(A))
= 2^0

Comment: @Shubhra:  While $n(℘(\emptyset)) = 2^0 = 1$, you have the exponentiation backwards in the rest of your chain of reasonsing (see again the Comment by Cameron Buie above).

Comment: @Shubhra As the comment above me said, your answer is still incorrect.